# Selenium can't find iframe after postback inside the iframe

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a test where I have to fill out some information inside an iframe. Getting access to the iframe work fine and I can fill out information inside the frame. The issue is that when I fill out a textbox 'A' it has a postback attached to it which reloads the content inside the iframe, to fill out another textbox 'B' depending on the information inside textbox A.

Here are my observations:
When I first locate the iframe it looks like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="<removed for clearity>">...</iframe>
```

After the postback has occurred it looks like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="<removed for clearity>" cd_frame_id_="668325d5a0a2a8cb76a92b9eb819d327">...</iframe>
```

So something changed.

In my C# code first find my frame like so (and yes that is the best way sadly):

```
var iframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@rawtitle=\"TIME\"]//table//tbody//tr//td//div//div//iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
```

I can easily enter text in textbox A:

```
var completed = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_txtCompletedHours")); 
completed.SendKeys("0,25");
```

Then I wait for textbox B to be filled but at this point, I can't locate it and I can't locate the iframe either. I tried to relocate the frame again to switch to it again, but I can't find the element. It hasn't moved position. It just got that cd_frame_id attribute. Here is the code where I try to re-locate the iframe:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        iframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@rawtitle=\"TIME\"]//table//tbody//tr//td//div//div//iframe"));
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
        invoiced = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_txtInvoiceHours")); 
        if (invoiced.Text == "0,25") // and wait for it
            break;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could not find element, retrying...");
    }
    finally
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

The code fails when I try to get hold of the iframe element.

How can I get hold of the iframe again, after the postback inside the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned when you fill out a textbox 'A' it has a postback attached, so we will take help of a unique `xpath` hich identifies the `<iframe>` as follows :

```
//Ensure that you are back to the base frame
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
//SwitchTo the intended frame
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'<removed for clearity>')]")));
```

Comment: I can't believe i didn't see that. Of cause i had to be in the original content before I can find the Frame. Frame is now perfectly detactable. I do have a problem that the textbox B content is showing correctly, but the text property for the element is empty. But that is another issue I will look into. Thank you